# Getting error when running jmeter master-slave using docker swarm mode "jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Error in rconfigure() method"

Tags: jmeter

Getting an error

> meter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is:      java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe" when running the jmeter in docker swarm mode 1 master and 1 slave.

This error log is from the docker-machine jmeter master details. Please suggest what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to resolve the issue by adding standard and extra libs plugins to my jmeter under lib/ext folder. Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide more inputs on this? I am trying to migrate 3.0 jmeter version to 3.3 and facing the same issue. Could not see anything as standard and extra libs plugin. Or I might be something here